# Scanning with AutoDoc Feed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been looking all over for some good documentation or tutorials on how to set up a scanning procedure (ultimately to generate pDF's).  Quite frankly the first 5 pages of Google suck.  The twain stuff is 10 + years old and the WIA stuff is so poorly documented is unreal.  I'm not looking for code but if any one can point me in the direction of some good documentation or tutorials I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck. I gave up on stuff like that because I couldn't find anything decent.

Comment: Yeah I just can't believe that something so common in enterprise software is such a pain in the ass lol

Comment: I believe you should start research about ISIS

Comment: Don't I need ISIS drivers for the devices then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that is facing this situation I ended up using ISIS however you do have to make sure that the hardware the client purchases / plans to use has ISIS drivers.